Is there a way to call a windows security key prompt (passkeys) with java?
Im developing a java application which implements the passkeys authentication. Is there a native java call to get access to this windows prompt, which opens up when a user is expected to authenticate with a passkey device or a PIN
Windows Security Key Prompt
In this sample project they use javascript to get the access to it, https://github.com/webauthn4j/webauthn4j. There they use navigator Navigator usage
Does java have something similar?
I can only use java and not javascript, I found a solution for how to call the certificate prompt in this thread windows security dialog for selecting a certificate in java. But nothing similar to the security key so far.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
